User.send_message() got an unexpected keyword argument 'chat_id'
I don't understand why it's not possible to write a chat message from a bot. I have configured to receive id_admin, I have configured the schedule library to receive messages at certain times, but I don't understand why it is NOT writing me chat messages. I can see from the logs that: User.send_message() got an unexpected keyword argument 'chat_id'
I realize that I can google deeper, but I haven't found an answer to help me solve my problem. I am following the correct syntax, why doesn't it want to write to me on behalf of the bot?
import logging
import random
import uuid
from telegram import Update, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, BotCommand, BotCommandScopeChat
from telegram.ext import Application, ApplicationBuilder, CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler, MessageHandler, filters, ContextTypes, ConversationHandler
from telegram.constants import ParseMode
import json
import os
import schedule
import asyncio
import re
from queue import Queue
import nest_asyncio
from warnings import filterwarnings
from telegram.warnings import PTBUserWarning

async def notify_admins(context, message: str):
    for admin_id in ADMIN_IDS:
        try:
            await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=admin_id, text=message, parse_mode=None)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Failed to send message to admin {admin_id}: {e}")

async def notify_cycle_user_count(context):
    num_users = len(cycle_users)
    message = f"There are currently {num_users} of users in the current loop."
    await notify_admins(context, message)

async def check_cycle_users(context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    logger.info("Cycle user check")
    if len(cycle_users) == 0:
        await notify_admins(context, "There are no users in the current loop.")
    else:
        await notify_admins(context, f"The current cycle has {len(cycle_users)} users.")
    logger.info("Cycle user verification completed")

async def scheduler(context):
    logger.info('Starting the scheduler')
    schedule.every(3).seconds.do(lambda: asyncio.create_task(notify_cycle_user_count(context)))

    while True:
        try:
            schedule.run_pending()
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Error in the scheduler: {e}")
            await asyncio.sleep(5)

async def set_commands(application):
    commands = [
        BotCommand("start", "start"),
        BotCommand("leave_feedback", "leave feedback")
    ]
    await application.bot.set_my_commands(commands)

async def main():
    application = ApplicationBuilder().token("TOKEN").build()

    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('start', start)],
        states={
            ASKING_EMAIL: [CallbackQueryHandler(button, pattern='start'), MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, get_email)],
            ASKING_NAME: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, get_name)],
            ASKING_POSITION: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, get_position)],
            CONFIRMING_NAME: [CallbackQueryHandler(confirm_name, pattern='^change_name$|^keep_name$')],
            CONFIRMING_POSITION: [CallbackQueryHandler(confirm_position, pattern='^change_position$|^keep_position$')],
            SHOWING_CARD: [CallbackQueryHandler(cycle_handler, pattern='^join_cycle$|^not_join_cycle$')]
        },
        fallbacks=[],
    )

    application.add_handler(conv_handler)
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler('show_all_users', show_all_users))
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler('match', match))
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler('clear_database', clear_database))
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler('leave_feedback', leave_feedback))
    application.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button_handler, pattern='^yes_meet$|^no_meet$'))
    application.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(feedback_handler, pattern='^feedback_1$|^feedback_2$|^feedback_3$'))
    application.add_error_handler(error_handler)

    asyncio.create_task(scheduler(application.bot))

    await application.run_polling()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nest_asyncio.apply()
    asyncio.run(main())

Here is an example of the bot outputting to me the number of users from my array every time a new one registers. Why can't it do that at a certain time? Maybe I'm not seeing some obvious solution? Help, please!
Image
I tried passing the ID chata into an array - it didn't work
Tried merging functions, it outputs me the number of people in the array every time a new registration occurs - didn't help.

Try:
context.bot.send_message(admin_id, message)

